# How to create Django model field to store users related to the model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a web application in python using the django framework. In my application users need to be able to apply for jobs.

I am unsure how to save a list of users who have applied for a job in the job model as a field.

Here is my `Job.py` model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="jobs")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    pay = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    #applicants = 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={
            'job_pk': self.id
            }
        )
```

I need to have the applicants field (which is currently commented out) to store the users who have applied for the job. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you'd need your models set up like this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    pay = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={
            'job_pk': self.id
          }
        )

class Applicant(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name="applicants")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This creates a one-to-many relationship from `Job` to `Applicant` and then a one-to-many relationship from the `Applicant` to the `User`.

Comment: Why a `OneToOne`field on `User` ? This will prevent a user to apply to more than one job.

Comment: No, in that case you'd create another `Applicant` object. It means only one user per `Applicant` object.

Comment: A ForeignKey on User already means "only one user per applicant" - else you'd  need a ManyToManyField - and while the OneToOne field will indeed allow to create many applicant for the same user (much to my suprise actually, I thought Django would prevent this, and IIRC it _did_ prevent it), it will at least prevent to get application from a user through user.applicant_set.all(). OneToOne field is mostly meant to express a "is a" relationship, not a "has" one.

Comment: @themanatuf Why can't you just have a field named applicants in the job model which contains the users who have applied? I don't understand your solution, could you explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I was mistaken. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TomFinet read this to help you understand: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a user can apply to many jobs and a job can have many users applying, the simple solution is a many to many relationship, defined by a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now you may want to keep track of additional informations about the application (date etc), in which case an explicit intermediate model might be handy:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date ⁼ models.DateTimeField(...)
    # etc

   class Meta:
       # you probably don't want the same user 
       # to apply twice to the same job
       unique_together = [("job", "user"),]
```

Comment: I don't understand what the first part of code in your answer does and what its purpose is. Could you elaborate? @bruno desthuilliers

Comment: The first snippet is an example of how to set up a simple (non valued) many to many relationship between two models. The second snippet is an example of how to manually create a valued many to many relationship thru an intermediate model. You have to choose either one or the other actually.

Answer (score 0):

As themanatuf said, other models with foreign keys and one to one relationships would do the trick.

I would advise you do the [Django 101 polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) first though - it is well explained and has very similar related-models architecture than the one you wish to build.

Have fun !